# Changed Blogger Background Transparency Now Images Not Transparent

Tags: html, image, blogger

I recently started building a website using Blogger's Ethereal template: http://healthmindspa.blogspot.com/

The background transparency was too light and it was hard to read the writing over the background image. Someone offered me the following fix to add as an HTML/JavaScript gadget:

```
<style>
.post-outer {
background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.7)!important;
}
</style>
```

It worked really well. The post transparency is now as I want it, but an unintentional side effect of this is that, when I upload images (business logo or social media buttons) with transparent backgrounds, the image background shows white - as you can see from the logo on the landing page.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks,

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add into css. This code remove white background from image.

```
.post-body img {
    background: transparent !important;
    /*box-shadow: none !important;*/ /*this remove shadow*/
}
```